# Prompt during sql script

Tags: sql, windows, sqlplus

My windows batch script calls a `sql` script in which a user is required to press `ENTER` during a prompt. This causes the program to pause during execution and wait for user input. Is it possible to preset the `ENTER` key in the `sql` script using a command?

Comment: What server is handling your SQL query?

Comment: @AhmadAl-Mutawa It's an Oracle 11g Database

Comment: main reason for this ";" is missing but can you post your windows batch screen for clear understanding?

Comment: Hey guys, i figured a simple way to do it - Add a blank line in the `sql` script at the prompt stage. The prompt would then simply take the `Return` key and the script proceeds.

Comment: Not sure if i should delete this question ...

Comment: You can post the answer, may be someone else can use this info..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured a simple way to do it - Add a blank line in the `sql` script at the prompt stage. The prompt would then simply take the `Return` key as input and proceeds to the subsequent stages.